# Use a USB Controller with Xoom without adapter

Tags: bluetooth, motorola-xoom, usb-peripherals, game-controllers

I would like to use an X-Box 360 Controller with my Motorola Xoom tablet, however the Controller uses USB to connect and I do not have the required USB OTG adapter to plug it directly into the tablet.

I've searched this site and Google but cannot find information on an alternative method of connecting the controller to the Xoom.

I'm hoping for a solution to pair these devices that involves either connecting both into my computer and bridging them somehow with adb or pairing my Xoom to my laptop using Bluetooth and sending the controller signal over this connection.

I've tried poking around the properties of the tablet and controller while they're plugged in but I haven't had any luck combining the two.  Does anyone have experience/know any techniques for doing either of these things?  Is there some other way for my Xoom to recognize the controller?

I could use either Windows 7 or Linux to make this work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you not use a USB OTG (On The Go) Cable. It will have a connection (microusb) at one end to fit to your tablet and a USB connection at the other (for many peripherals). This should surely connect your X Box Controller to your tablet. They are very cheap as well.

Alternatively, and maybe to be used in conjunction with see the following article from Pocketables entitled **"Guide to Game Controllers on Android"** written by A. Odegard on May 9th 2012

http://www.pocketables.com/2012/05/guide-to-game-controllers-on-android.html

Its is an excellent read

Comment: Damn you beat me too it ;)

Comment: @The Andro Nerd - What is this thing about "beating people to it", i've seen that before - is it a race or something lol

Comment: people always want to be the first to answer, because they are more likely to get upvoted/marked as the solution. If you post at the same time as someone else, but the other person submitted the response first, they 'beat you to the first answer'.

Comment: Ah I see, so the more answers you provide quickly, the higher up the ranks you go - is that right

Comment: Thank you @Simon, I appreciate the link.  Very informative.  I've never heard of the OTG Cable.  I was hoping for a solution that didn't involve going out and buying an adapter, but that may end up being my best bet.

Comment: @MattDavis I havent used one yet, but they sure are going to of tremendous use in the tablet world....and very cheap too

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid the only way you would be able to connect the controller to your Xoom is to purchase the aforementioned [USB OTG (On-The-Go) adapter](http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_trksid=p5197.m570.l1313&_nkw=usb+otg&_sacat=0&_from=R40).